# how to insert bible in my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

i m brand new to Android application development and now able to create few Activities and navigate among them.

 
Now i want to insert complete BIBLE into my application.

But, it's nearly impossible to write all BIBLE once again So some one could help me in sorting this out.

Thanks in advance.

mail id: kiran121296

Comment: Um.. this doesn't seem to really be a programming question. Seems like you can just Google for Bible.txt and stick it in your project folder.

Comment: can you direct me how to stick that big file(20 mb) into project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't yet comment because my reputation isn't high enough yet but I had to implement a spell checker for a class one time and we had to use a 500,000 word dictionary and it had to spell check a movie script and the King James edition of the bible.

What I did was (assuming you're on windows) is find a bible pdf or something online hit ctr+A to select it all then hit ctr+C to copy it and paste it in a text document. Also there are places like this http://www.sacred-texts.com/bib/osrc/ that have bibles in the form of text documents.

Now as far as implementing it goes, you can create a new xml file in your values folder in make a string then paste the whole text in there. If you need further clarification on the implementation part just tell me

To "import" a large amount of text you can go into you res/values folder and then (if you are using android studio) right click the values folder and select new->xml->values xml file. Name it something like bible_text or something. Just make sure the name doesn't contain any spaces. And put this line of code in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="my_text">
   My String here
</string>
</resources>
```

And just paste it in there.
Here's an example with just a small part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="my_text">
 Psalm 147
{147:1} Praise ye the LORD: for [it is] good to sing praises unto our
 God; for [it is] pleasant; [and] praise is comely.
{147:2} The LORD doth build up Jerusalem: he gathereth together the
 outcasts of Israel.
{147:3} He healeth the broken in heart, and bindeth up their wounds.
{147:4} He telleth the number of the stars; he calleth them all by
 [their] names.
{147:5} Great [is] our Lord, and of great power: his understanding [is]
 infinite.
{147:6} The LORD lifteth up the meek: he casteth the wicked down to the
 ground.
{147:7} Sing unto the LORD with thanksgiving; sing praise upon the harp
 unto our God:
{147:8} Who covereth the heaven with clouds, who prepareth rain for the
 earth, who maketh grass to grow upon the mountains.
{147:9} He giveth to the beast his food, [and] to the young ravens
 which cry.
{147:10} He delighteth not in the strength of the horse: he taketh not
 pleasure in the legs of a man.
{147:11} The LORD taketh pleasure in them that fear him, in those that
 hope in his mercy.
{147:12} Praise the LORD, O Jerusalem; praise thy God, O Zion.
{147:13} For he hath strengthened the bars of thy gates; he hath
 blessed thy children within thee.
{147:14} He maketh peace [in] thy borders, [and] filleth thee with the
 finest of the wheat.
{147:15} He sendeth forth his commandment [upon] earth: his word
 runneth very swiftly.
{147:16} He giveth snow like wool: he scattereth the hoar frost like
 ashes.
{147:17} He casteth forth his ice like morsels: who can stand before
 his cold?
{147:18} He sendeth out his word, and melteth them: he causeth his wind
 to blow, [and] the waters flow.
{147:19} He sheweth his word unto Jacob, his statutes and his judgments
 unto Israel.
{147:20} He hath not dealt so with any nation: and [as for his]
 judgments, they have not known them. Praise ye the LORD.
    </string>
</resources>
```

Now all you have to do to use the text is refer to it's name that you gave it

Here's an example of how to refer to it in xml. Where my_text is the name of your text

```
android:text="@string/my_text"
```

Or in java

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.my_text);
```

Comment: i am very happy to read your response, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm a Windows user i actually want to how to import bible .txt file into android project